# (Obj-C) Is there any way to allocate all my NSDecimalNumbers at once for use in various parts of a calculator-style app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm working with about 10 or so NSDecimalNumbers in my app, but I'm having trouble finding a way to just allocate them all at once for use by all the various buttons on the storyboard.  The @interface of viewcontroller.h would've been the logical location, but it won't let me go past "NSDecimalNumber *one."  What should I do?

Also, as I need the values in each object simply altered as I go, (as opposed to deleted and recreated), what should I do about memory release?

I'm still fairly new to programming, so try not to be overly technical.  Thanks in advance!

@Kurt Revis 
All right, let me try to give an example: 
In viewcontroller.h, we have 1 outlet and 2 actions, connected to a label and 10 buttons.  We also have the NSDecimalNumbers screen and digit.

```
@interface viewcontroller:UIViewController{
IBOutlet UILabel *CalculatorScreen;
NSDecimalNumber *screen;
NSDecimalNumber *digit;}
- (IBAction)DigitPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)OperatorPressed:(id)sender;
```

When "DigitPressed" is hit, the NSDecimalNumber "screen" is calculated like so in viewcontroller.m:

```
- (IBAction)DigitPressed:(id)sender {    
screen= [[screen decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy: ten] decimalNumberByAdding:digit];}
```

(where "ten" is also an NSDN.)  But in order to do that (or so I thought), "screen" has to be allocated like so:

```
screen=[NSDecimalNumber alloc];
```

so now we get this:

```
- (IBAction)DigitPressed:(id)sender {    
screen=[NSDecimalNumber alloc];
screen= [[screen decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy: ten] decimalNumberByAdding:digit];}
```

-- but then it's allocated to a new address with each hit.  Similarly, if I try to use the number in my "OperatorPressed" section, it will have to be independently allocated.

Therefore, I need a way to allocate the memory once and then just use the number over and over in all methods of my .m file.

Comment: Explain something to me. Why are you allocating NSDecimalNumbers? Why don't you just define them as properties and alter them that way. You seem to be making this much to difficult. How much Obj-C experience do you have? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Not much.  I know enough C++ to get by (well, that's relative), but I really just jumped into Objective-C and have been using google for most things.  Everything I've seen so far has told me to initialize them with [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithWhatever:].  So are you telling me I would only have to make each number by doing, say, "@property NSDecimalNumber *one" in the .h file?

I've gotten warnings concerning ARC, so I'm assuming it's on by default.

Comment: You are going to have to give much more detail before we can help you. You're describing what (you think) your code is doing, but you're not actually showing your code. A [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) is the ideal to shoot for, but even a step in that direction would help.

Comment: Updated with example. @KurtRevis

Comment: @classicalpianoguy, In general, you don't need to initialize and allocate every item. ARC does a lot of this for. Although sometimes it is necessary, like if you want to create a new class with it's own view not in the storyboard, then you could do this. But for simple properties, it is not necessary. Now, I have not used NSDecimal, so I am not positive on how that works. I am assuming it is like NSInteger.

Comment: @AceLegend: actually, NSDecimalNumber is an object, and not a primitive type like NSInteger, so it does indeed need to be initialized.

Comment: @Inafziger, Oh, okay then. Good to know. Anyway, there seems to be a pretty good solution already.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go through and make this stuff work.  Also, I'll change the case on some of your names to match typical Objective-C practice -- hope you don't mind.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *calculatorScreen;
    NSDecimalNumber *screen;
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

You need to initialize `screen` to a reasonable starting value. Since your class is a view controller, a good place to do that is `-viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // in case your superclass needs to do any work

    screen = [NSDecimalNumber zero];

    // also, make sure it shows up in the UI
    calculatorScreen.text = [screen stringValue]; // Convert from NSDecimalNumber to NSString, and pushes it into the label
}
```

Next, the digit buttons. It's unclear whether you expected there to be one `digitPressed:` method that is called by all 10 digit buttons, or whether it was supposed to be for only one of the buttons.  To start, it's easiest to make a separate action for each button.

Here's the method for the "1" button:

```
- (IBAction)digit1Pressed:(id)sender {
    // Create intermediate values
    NSDecimalNumber* one = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:0 isNegative:NO];  // 1 * 10^0 = 1
    NSDecimalNumber* ten = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:1 isNegative:NO];  // 1 * 10^1 = 10

    // Compute the new result
    NSDecimalNumber* result = [[screen decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:ten] decimalNumberByAdding:one];

    // Put the result back in the screen
    screen = result;

    // and update the UI
    calculatorScreen.text = [screen stringValue];
}
```

Similarly, the "2" button would be hooked up to this action:

```
- (IBAction)digit2Pressed:(id)sender {
    NSDecimalNumber* two = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:2 exponent:0 isNegative:NO];  // 1 * 10^0 = 1
    NSDecimalNumber* ten = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:1 isNegative:NO];  // 1 * 10^1 = 10

    // take a shortcut and don't bother with the `result` variable
    screen = [[screen decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:ten] decimalNumberByAdding:two];
    calculatorScreen.text = [screen stringValue];
}
```

And so on. Note that we didn't have to remember "one", "two", and "ten" in the view controller -- we can just create them when we need them, and let them get deallocated when we're done with them.  (Yes it's slightly more inefficient, but these objects are tiny and lightweight; you could create thousands of them every second and nobody would notice.)

Your next question: isn't it stupid to have 10 separate "digit" actions? Yes. You could instead have one "digitPressed" action that looked at the sender, determined which button it was, and then did the right thing.

An easy way to tell which button is which: When you create the button, set its `tag` to be the same as its digit.  You can set this via code, or in the interface builder. Then, the action method looks up the sender's tag.

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(id)sender {
    NSDecimalNumber* digit = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:[sender tag] exponent:0 isNegative:NO];  // digit * 10^0
    NSDecimalNumber* ten = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:1 isNegative:NO];  // 1 * 10^1 = 10
    screen = [[screen decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:ten] decimalNumberByAdding:digit];
    calculatorScreen.text = [screen stringValue];
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I am using sender tag to determine which digit is which.  But I'm pretty sure your answer actually solved my problem (which was even dumber than I realized, sorry for wasting everyone's time) right at the beginning.  I just have to initialize my numbers in -viewDidLoad.  Thanks for the help!  

One more quick thing though -- you didn't mention release, autoreleasepool, or NSAutoreleasepool at all.  Would I include them in -viewDidUnload, or are they even necessary?

Comment: They aren't necessary. ARC takes care of retaining and releasing for you. And even in non-ARC code, you rarely have to manually touch autorelease pools yourself, because the system creates them for you before calling your code.

Comment: Technically you should be using a NSNumberFormatter to convert to a string so that it is localized.  (Especially with results).  That's probably for a different question, but it is better to think of these rhings in the beginning...